# passing byte array from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, arrays

As the title suggests, I'd like to pass a byte array from c++ to python. I understand I would need to convert my byte array into a PyObject somehow but this is where I got stuck. Is there anyone who can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyBytes_FromString` to the rescue assuming Python3+:

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html

Under Python2.x `PyString_FromString`:

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html

Comment: I'm using an opencv matrix to byte conversion like this  <br/>std::memcpy(bytes,image.data,size * sizeof(byte));  so this is not a string. How do I use it with PyBytes_FromString?

Comment: @las `*_FromString` functions take `const char*` as arg. You say that you have a byte array. So I assume that's exactly what it is. It's a bit confusing but strings and byte arrays meant the same thing back in days. If you allow nulls in your sequence of bytes then `*_FromStringAndSize` might be a better choice.

Comment: Anyway I don't know opencv but if you have anything else then first you have to find a way to convert it to `char*`.